# AngularJS UI router - Pass angular object to ui-router controller method?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I want to pass the data of the function PhoneList() to the UI-Router controller function to the state 'phonedescription'.

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/phone")

  $stateProvider
    .state('phone', {
        url: "/phone",
        templateUrl: "index.html"
    })
    .state('phonedescription', {
          url: "/description",
          templateUrl: "description.html",
          controller: function($scope){
            //Want to access the angular object to pass the attributes to this controller


          }
    }
});

function PhoneList($scope, $http, $templateCache)
{
    $scope.list = function() {
      $scope.phones = //get data from backend
    }
    $scope.list();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are defining PhoneList as a loose function outside of the angular framework. Look into using a service instead. You can then inject that service into your phonedescription controller.